Неинформативный ответ от яндекс саджеста
При попытке сделать запрос через апи с параметром "text" "казань, луговая 2а", я получаю короткий ответ

Казань, Луговая улица, 2А
Казань,Луговая улица, 2
Казань, Односторонняя Луговая улица, 2

в то время как через карты ответ куда более развернутый и релевантный, так как много одниковых адресов в разных жилых массивах

Луговая улица, 2А жилой массив Озёрный, Авиастроительный район,
Казань, Республика Татарстан
Луговая улица, 2А жилой массив Вознесенское, Советский район,
Казань, Республика Татарстан
Луговая улица, 2А жилой массив Борисоглебское, Авиастроительный
район, Казань, Республика Татарстан
Луговая улица, 2А жилой массив Вишнёвка, Советский район, Казань,
Республика Татарстан

есть какой-то способ победить это?

Исходя из информации на сайте возникает два вопроса, есть ли у вас лицензия и пробовали ли вы обращаться с этим вопросом к менеджеру (на сайте)? Так же на главной странице в разделе демонстрации показали возможность ограничивать отображаемые данные, так что, возможно, стоит рассмотреть вариант с настройкой параметров.
